# FB dialog app name

Tags: ios, iphone, facebook, fbdialogs

When I try to share on Facebook using presentOSIntegratedShareDialogModallyFrom, I can not see the app name. I use the following code:

```
[FBSettings setDefaultDisplayName:[[FBSettings defaultDisplayName] precomposedStringWithCanonicalMapping]];
FBLinkShareParams *params = [[FBLinkShareParams alloc] init];
params.link = [NSURL URLWithString:[arrDetailsOfTour valueForKey:@"WebAddress"]];
params.picture = [NSURL URLWithString:[arrDetailsOfTour objectForKey:@"ImageUrl"]];
params.name = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[arrDetailsOfTour valueForKey:@"CompanyName"]];

[FBDialogs presentOSIntegratedShareDialogModallyFrom:self initialText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[arrDetailsOfTour valueForKey:@"CompanyName"]] image:toursImageView.image url:[NSURL URLWithString:[arrDetailsOfTour valueForKey:@"WebAddress"]] handler:^(FBOSIntegratedShareDialogResult result, NSError *error) {
    if(error) {
        NSLog(@"Error: %@", error.description);
    } else {
        NSLog(@"Success!");
    }
}];
```

but I am not able to see the app name in the post. I have put Facebook Display name in plist, but still it does not show. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

Apple controls the UI for the iOS integrated dialog, and they don't show the app name. The native Facebook Share Dialogs and the web dialogs will.